# QT Bluetooth Not Finding Local Raspberry Pi Device

Tags: c++, qt, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to run QT Bluetooth on a Raspberry Pi 3, but it's not finding any local devices. I've boiled down my code to as simple as possible. I've got BlueZ 5.3 installed on the target. I can use hciconfig and bluetoothctl on the target to find the local bluetooth device and scan for remote devices. I've tried everything I can think of, but nothing I see says it shouldn't just work.

```
#include <qbluetoothlocaldevice.h>
#include <qdebug.h>

int main()
{

    QBluetoothLocalDevice localDevice;

    // Check if Bluetooth is available on this device
    if (localDevice.isValid()) 
        qDebug() << "Found device";
    else
         qDebug() << "No valid devices";
}
```

Comment: Does QBluetoothLocalDevice::allDevices() return an empty list?

Comment: Yes, it returns an empty list.